# passing parameter to singleton and define member based on that

Tags: dart, parameters, singleton

I need to pass a parameter to a singleton and define a class member based on the passed parameter.

This is the code I'm using that actually does not work:

```
class MyService {
  static final MyService _singleton = ImapService._internal();

  String level;
  MyClass _client;

  factory MyService({level = 'HIGH'}) {
    _singleton.level = level;

    return _singleton;
  }

  MyService._internal() {
    if (level == 'LOW') {
      _client = new Class1();
    } else {
      _client = new Class2();
    }
  }
}
```

The problem is that the `MyService._internal()` function is always called before the `factory`, so the `level` variable is always null in the function, and my code never goes in the `If` statement.

Comment: What should happen if the singleton has already been used once and one are calling `MyService` with a different `level` argument?

Comment: Ideally modify the singleton to get new level argument. But its ok even if it returns the singleton used the first time.

Comment: Should this modification happen for existing users of the singleton?

Comment: No. To not asking too much, its ok if the singleton remains the same after the first 
instancing. The following times it just could ignore the level argument.

Answer (score 1):

You want a singleton with mutable state. That's somewhat reasonable.

If you go with state on the instance, you need valid initial values.
Something like:

```dart
class MyService {
  static final MyService _singleton = MyService._internal();
  String _level;
  MyClass _clientCache;
  String get level => level;
  set level(String level) {
    if (_level != level) {
      _level = level;
      _clientCache = level == "LOW" ? Class1() : Class2();
    }
  }
  factory MyService({String level = "HIGH"}) => _singleton..level = level;
  MyService._internal() : _level = "HIGH", _clientCache = Class1();
}
```

You could also just store that state in a global variable then. That would allow you lazy initialization for the `_class` getter.

Something like:

```dart
class MyService {
  static final MyService _singleton = const MyService._internal();

  static String _level = "HIGH";
  static MyClass _clientCache = _classFromLevel(_level);

  String get level => _level;
  void set level(String level) {
    if (_level != level) {
      _level = level;
      _clientCache = _classFromLevel(level);
    }
  }

  MyClass _client => _clientCache;

  factory MyService({level = 'HIGH'}) => _instance..level = level;

  const MyService._internal();

  static MyClass _classFromLevel(String level) =>
    level == "LOW" ? Class1() : Class2();
}
```

(Do consider whether you *really* need a singleton. A mutable singleton object is just a glorified global variable with all the inherent problems of those.)

Answer (score 1):

I think the most simple solution you can do is the following (based on the latest requirement updates in the comments: "its ok if the singleton remains the same after the first instancing. The following times it just could ignore the level argument."):

```
class MyService {
  static MyService _singleton;

  MyClass _client;

  factory MyService({String level = 'HIGH'}) =>
      _singleton ??= MyService._internal(level);

  MyService._internal(String level) {
    if (level == 'LOW') {
      _client = new Class1();
    } else {
      _client = new Class2();
    }
  }
}
```